AWS dotnet 8 lambda missing fonts when creating Excel file
I have a dotnet 8 C# application running in AWS Lambda. Prior to dotnet 8 I used dotnet 6 and the Excel file creation was working as expected. Now, when the project is upgraded to dotnet 8, I get some errors when an Excel file is being created.

[Error] Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction: Unknown error responding to request: FontException:
SixLabors.Fonts.FontException: No fonts found installed on the machine.

I'm using the NPOI nuget, version 2.7.0.
I tried adding the SixLabels.Fonts nuget (2.0.3) but to no avail.
Anyone knows how to get AWS Lambda to load some default fonts. I'm not using docker and would preferably not switch to docker images.
Code below. Error is thrown at row where worksheet.AutoSizeRow(rowIndex); is called:
ISheet worksheet = workbook.CreateSheet(customerId);

#region styling
IFont boldFont = workbook.CreateFont();
boldFont.IsBold = true;

var cellStyleCategory = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleCategory.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
cellStyleCategory.SetFont(boldFont);
((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyleCategory).SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.LightGreen));

var cellStyleSubcategory = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleSubcategory.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
cellStyleSubcategory.SetFont(boldFont);
((XSSFCellStyle)cellStyleSubcategory).SetFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(IndexedColors.LightYellow));

var richTextSupport = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
richTextSupport.WrapText = true;

var cellStyleLogo = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
IFont boldFontSize1 = workbook.CreateFont();
boldFontSize1.IsBold = true;
boldFontSize1.FontHeightInPoints = 20;
cellStyleLogo.SetFont(boldFontSize1);

var cellStyleCustomer = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
var boldFontSize2 = workbook.CreateFont();
boldFontSize2.IsBold = true;
boldFontSize2.FontHeightInPoints = 16;
cellStyleCustomer.SetFont(boldFontSize2);
#endregion styling

var previousRow = -1;
var highestCellCount = 4;

#region header
var LOGOCOLUMN = 0;
IRow firstRow = worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
firstRow.CreateCell(LOGOCOLUMN).SetCellValue("App name");
firstRow.Cells[0].CellStyle = cellStyleLogo;
worksheet.AddMergedRegion(new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(previousRow, previousRow, LOGOCOLUMN, highestCellCount));

var CUSTOMERCOLUMN = 0;
IRow secondRow = worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
secondRow.CreateCell(CUSTOMERCOLUMN).SetCellValue("Foobar");
secondRow.Cells[0].CellStyle = cellStyleCustomer;
worksheet.AddMergedRegion(new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(previousRow, previousRow, CUSTOMERCOLUMN, highestCellCount));

worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);

var K = 0;
var S = 1;
var L = 2;
var C = 3;
var INFO = 4;

IRow header = worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
header.CreateCell(K).SetCellValue("K");
header.CreateCell(S).SetCellValue("S");
header.CreateCell(L).SetCellValue("E");
header.CreateCell(C).SetCellValue("I");
header.CreateCell(INFO).SetCellValue("I/h");
#endregion header

labelList.Categories.ForEach(c =>
{
    c.SubCategories.ForEach(s =>
    {
        IRow category = worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
        category.CreateCell(K).SetCellValue(c.Name);
        category.Cells[0].CellStyle = cellStyleCategory;
        category.CreateCell(S).SetCellValue(s.Name);
        category.Cells[1].CellStyle = cellStyleSubcategory;
        s.Labels.ForEach(l =>
        {
            IRow label = worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
            label.CreateCell(L).SetCellValue("Bar");
            var components = new StringBuilder();
            l.Components.ForEach(lc =>
            {
                components.Append("Quux\n");
            });
            label.CreateCell(C).SetCellValue(components.ToString());
            label.Cells[1].CellStyle = richTextSupport;

            label.CreateCell(INFO).SetCellValue("Monkey");
            label.Cells[2].CellStyle = richTextSupport;
        });

        ++previousRow;
    });
});

// Make sure row and column content is visible
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= previousRow; rowIndex++)
{
    worksheet.AutoSizeRow(rowIndex);  // <-- error is thrown here
}

for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= highestCellCount; columnIndex++)
{
    worksheet.AutoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
}

worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);
worksheet.CreateRow(++previousRow);

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
{
    workbook.Write(memoryStream);
    byte[] binaryBlob = memoryStream.ToArray();
    return (binaryBlob, workbook);
}


I am running into the same issue. Were you able to resolve it without changing layers/images?

Just noticing that the System Requirements only include up to .NET 6
https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi?tab=readme-ov-file#system-requirement

No, no luck yet. Did you solve it?

My solution so far, has been to remove the parts with worksheet.AutoSizeRow(rowIndex); and worksheet.AutoSizeColumn(columnIndex);, since they appears to expect fonts to exist in the lambda. To get the same result the user needs to open the Excel file and adjust row and column sizes manually.
